# format of the log file format for splunk

Tags: splunk

The current log file name I have is: catalina.2010-02-24.log.

I want to add this for splunk indexing, but i am running into problems, since there is no static file name, since everyday tomcat renames the log file.

[tail:///var/logs/catalina.2010-02-24.log] is not gonna work. Is there a way around this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index either the whole directory, or use wildcards to select the appropriate files.

In your case, `[monitor://var/logs/catalina.*.log]` should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script that runs as a daily cron job which symlinks the file based on the date to catalina.current.log or something such as this.

Example:

```
ln -sf /var/logs/catalina.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log /var/logs/catalina.current.log
```

Then of course just use `catalina.current.log` to access the current day's log.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about Splunk, so this may cause problems.

Comment: You could also index `/var/logs/catalina.*.log` I believe. Or put the logs in `/var/logs/catalina` and monitor this directory.